# BMW 318d 2006 e90 Starter Problem?

Tags: bmw, diesel, starter

I have this weird issue, where my BMW starts When Its cold, but once the car heats up, It turns over after a couple of tries sometimes (10-20) sometimes it will not turn over at all, when that happens when I try to start the car I can hear the sound of the motor starting its like an electric buzz sound for about 2 seconds and the sound ends the car shakes a bit and thats it, If the car wouldn't start when its cold i would have no doubt that it is the starter.

Any Ideas?

(By turn over the starter is spining the engine)

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! When you say "turn over" do you mean start? We usually differentiate "turning over" to mean the engine will crank (starter is spinning the engine). If it's not "turning over", it means you turn the key and get nothing. You are using the same term throughout, which doesn't really make sense. Could you edit your question to ensure I'm on the right track here?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Hi, Sorry i have updated my question